# Error Invalid template file: 'Magento_Theme... While trying to create custom header using custom theme

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.3

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/Customtheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="authorization-link" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="top.links" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="header.panel.wrapper" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="header.container" remove="true" />

        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <container name="custom.header" htmlClass="headerSection" htmlTag="div" before="main.content">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="navigation.sections" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/customheader.phtml">

                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/design/frontend/Vendor/Customtheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/customheader.phtml**

```
<h1>Custom Header Content here</h1>
```

It's giving me this error

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid
> template file: 'Magento_Theme::html/customheader.phtml' in module: ''
> block's name: 'navigation.sections'

Comment: Your code seems correct.. just try to clear cache and deploy content if in production mode..

Comment: I tried both commands "clear cache" and "static content deploy."

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<referenceBlock name="navigation.sections">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Theme::html/customheader.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```